# Is it possible to listen for changes to a shadow with aws-greengrass-core-sdk?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

Currently we are using the greengrass core shadow to pass a config file to our app, if any changes are made to the shadow we want to update the config. Currently we are using the aws-iot-device-sdk and subscribing to the shadow, in an ideal situation we would like to use the aws-greengrass-core-sdk to listen and retreive the shadow.

Any help is extremely appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.

Have you tried looking at the MQTT topic $aws/things//shadow/update/delta? This should show all changes to the shadow documents. Theres a handful of automatically generated topics for these purposes.

More information look under the section observing state changes in the official documentation. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/using-device-shadows.html